# Get 2D mouse delta along 2D angle?

Tags: 2d, mathematics

I'm trying to develop my own transformation gizmo (with x, y & z handles/arrows the user can grab and move, like in game engines), however, I'm not sure how I should calculate the 2D mouse delta along the 2D angle of the grabbed handle axis. I already have converted the base and tip of the handle/arrow to screen-space, and have calculated the screen-space points' angle between the screen-space base and tip. I'm just stuck on taking the X & Y mouse delta and getting the acceleration of the delta along that 2D angle. I've made a little visualization; [image: diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is [projecting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) the mouse vector to the axis vector.

First, subtract the base position vector from the tip position vector to get the axis as a vector, next subtract the base position from the position of the mouse to get the vector pointing to the position of the mouse.

Use the following formula with these vectors:

```
projected = mouse ⋅ (axis / |axis|)
```

where `⋅` means dot product and `|v|` is the magnitude of **v**. This should result in a scalar.